# How to avoid self referring an object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zustand

I have this kind of code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
export const useStore = create<StoreState>((set, get) => {
  const jwtClient = createJWTClient(useStore);
  return {
    dummyState: createDummySlice(set, get, jwtClient),
    userState: createUserSlice(set, get, jwtClient),
  };
});
```

The function `createJWTClient` needs the `useStore` in order to access user tokens and make auth calls.

Also the slices need the jwtClient in order to call some methods with this instance.

The problem is that I refer the `useStore` object before is actually created but I thought this is just a pointer thing but Typescript complains that:

```
TS7022: 'useStore' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

TS7022: 'jwtClient' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally including a link to the same code in the TypeScript playground. ([Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/N9y97N): you can see there are many reference errors even after importing `zustand`. You'll need to fix those before someone can help address your problem.)

Comment: "*Typescript complains*" - well it complains that it cannot infer the type correctly if there are circular references and such. Did you try what the message says and just provide a type annotation for `useStore` and/or `jwtClient`?